# How to create user with read-write access for specific DB only in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-security

I've created user by shell:

```
use testDB
db.createUser({user: 'testUser', pwd: 'password', roles: ["readWrite"]})
```

But the user can see and modify another databases also (like admin).
I've checked by `db.runCommand({connectionStatus : 1})` and 'testUser' is logged in the session.

How to create user with read-write access just for specific database?

Comment: In the configuration, what is [security.authorization](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/index.html#security.authorization) set to?

Comment: You need to get an idea of what is authentication and authorization in MongoDB. Authorization allows a user to have specific access to a resource. See this tutorial [Security - Enable Access Control](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/tutorial/enable-authentication/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can perform all user maintenance in admin database namespace.
So, for your case, you can run following commands from your mongo shell:

```
use admin

db.createUser({
  user: "testUser",
  pwd: "password",
  roles: [
    { role: "readWrite", db: "<your_database>" }
  ]
})
```

More details can be found at MongoDB documentation:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createUser/